# Display Django ForeignKey as Textarea in CreateView

Tags: python, django

By default, Django will display a `ForeignKey` field as a dropdown menu with **all** of the valid `ForeignKeys` available for selection. Instead, I want to display a `TextArea` and have users enter in a value on their own. How is this done?

Adjusting the widget in `forms.py` is **not** enough, as Django will still not recognize `TextArea` input as a valid Object.

Comment: what is the goal of that hack? I mean C, R(filtering), U, D?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should redefine the field as a CharField, and define its clean_field method to return the related object. So if the field was called "other_model" and was a FK to OtherModel:

```
class MyForm(forms.ModelForm):
    other_model = forms.CharField()

    def clean_other_model(self):
        value = self.cleaned_data['other_model']
        try:
            other_instance = OtherModel.objects.get(value_field=value)
        except OtherModel.DoesNotExist:
            raise forms.ValidationError('enter a valid value')
        return other_instance
```

Comment: This works! The only change I have made is returning 'other_instance' instead of 'value.' Thank you, I've been stumped on this for some time.

Comment: Yes you're right, it should have returned the instance - edited.